# Determine the current time

Tags: logical-deduction

When ten-year-old Rohan wanted to know the current time, his uncle Rakesh looked at his 12-hour analog wristwatch, and replied:

> “In four minutes, it will be exactly ten times as many seconds past the half-hour as it was minutes before the same half-hour the last time the two  hands were at a right angle this afternoon.”

Determine the current time, assuming that the above conversation took place after 12:00 P.M. but before 12:00 A.M.

Comment: what do you mean, "at the next four minutes"? In four minutes?

Comment: @sousben The phrase "at the next four minutes" means four minutes from the current time.

Comment: does the question mean that the hands of the clocks are in right angle currently?

Comment: @sousben The time when the two hands were in right angles, the hour hand and the minute hand were precisely situated on two distinct minute marks

Comment: how does this answer my question?

Comment: Are you sure there's only 1 correct answer to this?..

Comment: "Determine the current time, assuming that the above conversation took place after 12:00 P.M. but before 12:00 A.M." - What difference does this make on a 12 hour analog clock? Is this implying that the answer is in 24 hour format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be

> 15:31 The last 90deg was at 15:00, 30 min before the second half of the hour. In 4 minutes it will be 15:35, 300s after the second half of the hour

or

> 13:27:30 (rounding the fractions of second). The last 90deg was at 13:21 that is 9 minutes before the second half hour. In 4 minutes it will be 1:31:30 which is 90s after the second half hour

or many other possible solutions...

The question seems to imply a unique answer so I may not have understood it well

Comment: On a 12-hour watch, I don't think it could be 15:31.

Comment: @DKrueger why not? the next right angle is only at 15:32

Comment: Because on a 12-hour watch, there is no 15. ;)

Comment: I think your answer fits well for the specified conditions, just maybe do time corrections, and add all possibilities which you also saw. *just to note, afternoon might be only till 4/6/8p.m. But should be not later. :)